# PHP script generating blank page as output but works fine in WAMP

Tags: php, mysql

I am really confused, a script of mine works perfectly in wamp but when i try to run it in my ubuntu apache2 server i get a blank page as output, the same thing happens when i uploaded it to a webserver and executed the script.
I could pinpoint that the error is caused due to the presence of this line of code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

even if i comment it out the problem persists, only deleting this line will allow me to get any kind of output. Even a simple `echo` wont work if this line is present.

I am posting the whole script, below may be you people can help me understand the reason behind this strange behavior.

```
<?php 

session_start(); // start up the PHP session! 

//Connect to mysql

include 'conn.php';

// Table name
$tbl_name = "tailor.employee"; 

//Get and initialize variables
$op = $_POST['op'];
$cusid = $_POST['cusid'];

if($op=="2")
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tailor.order WHERE cusid ='$cusid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
 if($count!=0)
    {
        $order = array();
        $oid = array();
        $day = array();
        $month = array();
        $year = array();
        $quan = array();
        $i=0;

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $cusid = $row['cusid'];
                $cname = $row['cname'];
                $phone = $row['phone'];
                $order[$i] = $row['type'];
                $oid[$i] = $row['oid'];
                $day[$i] = $row['day'];
                $month[$i] = $row['month'];
                $year[$i] = $row['year'];
                $quan[$i] = $row['quan'];
                $i=$i+1;
                }
                echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br>";
                echo "<pre><p><strong>Customer ID   : </strong>".$cusid."</pre></p>";
                echo "<pre><p><strong>Customer Name : </strong>".$cname."</pre></p>";
                echo "<pre><p><strong>Phone Number  : </strong>".$phone."</pre></p>";
                echo '<table border="1">';
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Quantity</td>";
                echo "<td>Order ID</td>";
                echo "<td>Particulars</td>";
                echo "<td>Delivery Date</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr><td>";
                $icount = count($oid);
                for($k=0;$k<$icount;$k++)
                {

                    echo $quan[$k];
                    echo "<br>";
                }

                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                for($k=0;$k<$icount;$k++)
                {

                    echo $oid[$k];
                    echo "<br>";
                }
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                for($j=0;$j<$icount;$j++)
                {

                    echo $order[$j];
                    echo "<br>";
                }
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                for($l=0;$l<$icount;$l++)
                {

                    echo $day[$l]."/".$month[$l]."/".$year[$l];
                    echo "<br>";
                }
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
                echo '<br><br><p ALIGN = "center"><a href ="order1.html">Place New Order</a></p>';
      }

unset($_SESSION['cusid']);  
unset($_SESSION['oid']);
unset($_SESSION['type']);
unset($_SESSION['cname']);
unset($_SESSION['phone']);
unset($_SESSION['address']);
}
if($op=="1")
{
    header('location:order1.html');
}


?>
```

The app is live and can be accessed by visiting http://www.techb.wilips.com/login.html
The login **user name is modern** and **password is modern@123**
To view the error page, just login, add an order and follow the steps then on the 3rd step where you have the **Operation drop down menu**, select **Print Order**

Comment: Maybe you didn't load `mysql` extension, check it with `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Other scripts in the same app where i interact with mysql works just fine

Comment: No error_log interresting content?

Comment: Put this in the start of your code, to php shows the error: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/vol8/wilips.com/wilip_13152617/htdocs/order3.php on line 22 this is error i got

Comment: @RickRoy This error means your `mysql_query` failed.

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions in the code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: If it works on WAMP and not on LAMP, you might have missed letter casing. Win is not case sensitive, but Lin is, and this affects names of databases and tables. Also, be sure that your database on server is consistent with the one on the Windows machine.

Comment: Rodrigo i looked up the cause for it and it seems for some reason this query wont work **$sql = "INSERT INTO tailor.order (cname, phone, cusid, oid, type, price, day, month, year, address, ddate, dmon, dyear, quan)
VALUES ('$cname', '$phone', '$cusid', '$oid', 'Shirt', '$price', '$day', '$month', '$year', '$address', '$day1', '$mon1', '$year1', '$quan')";**